# Обновить данные в одной таблице, а условия сравнения в других

Tags: sql, sql-server

Мне нужно прогнать UPDATE в таблице, но немного необычным способом, что-то вроде того (можно ли так сделать?)

```
UPDATE table1 from table2 WHERE table2.id=table3.id
```

(да да, апдейт в таблице1, но условия идут с 2 и 3 таблицей)

Когда попытался так сделать, не могу обратиться к таблице 3, он ее не видит

Comment: Пока то, что Вы рассказываете - бессмысленно. Ибо Ваша FROM вернёт набор записей - и как прикажете определять, какую из них надо использовать для каждой конкретной обновляемой записи? Рекомендую создать fiddle (или хотя бы добавить в вопрос скрипты создания и наполнения таблиц) и показать требуемый результат на именно таких данных, с объяснением, почему именно так. *не могу обратиться к таблице 3, он ее не видит* Отож... её в FROM нету. Должно быть `FROM table2, table3` или типа того.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cинтаксис предложения `UPDATE` c `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE 
    t1
SET 
    t1.c1 = t2.c2,
    t2.c2 = expression,
    ...   
FROM 
    t1
    [INNER | LEFT] JOIN t2 ON join_predicate
WHERE 
    where_predicate;
```